# Retrieve artifacts from public repository using PAT

Tags: github, github-actions, access-token, github-api

I am trying to download the latest artifact of a repository I don't own.

 The API just gives me the following error:

```json
{
  "message": "You must have the actions scope to download artifacts.",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#download-an-artifact"
}
```

The thing is, I don't see an "actions" box in when creating a personal access token. Here are the possible options, my token has access to "repo" and "workflow"[image: possible scopes for creating a PAT]

 Is this on purpose, or have I missed something (another endpoint)?

Comment: Share what options to do have

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps):

Check headers to see what OAuth scopes you have, and what the API action accepts:

```bash
$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com/users/codertocat -I
HTTP/2 200
X-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: user
```

- `X-OAuth-Scopes` lists the scopes your token has authorized.
- `X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes` lists the scopes that the action checks for.

So replace `codertocat` by the user of the repository you do not own, and check
`X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes` to discover the expected scopes.
Compare them with `X-OAuth-Scopes`.